# К вопросу о политкорректности

Tags: этикет

Не будет сейчас касаться американский маразмов, а спросить я хочу о нашем языке. Так вот, насколько оскорбительными и грубыми являются прозвища разных народов, например: русский — кацап, украинец — хохол, кавказец — хач и т.д.? А то у меня был случай, когда начали писать "хохол", "хохляцкий". Я сделала замечание, что, вообще-то, это оскорбительно звучит, а на меня тут же накинулись, обвинили в национализме (вот уж не страдаю!) и т.д.
Скажите, пожалуйста, права ли я была, сделав (в достаточно корректной форме) замечание?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Я не воспринимаю "хохол" как оскорбительное, скорее как разговорное, у меня тётка хохлушка, так "хохлушка" и вовсе звучит даже ласково,но сейчас, в связи с современными националистическими настроениями, действительно слово звучит как пренебрежительное, его, думаю, следует избегать.
Вот КАЦАП, [араб. ḳaṣṣāb — мясник] до революции в словарях давалось  как бранное, это было шовинистическое обозначение русского в отличие от украинца в устах украинцев-националистов, возникшее на почве национальной вражды.

"Хохол"-исторически сформировавшийся образ украинца на фоне других народностей прошлого. И он неразрывно связан с украинскими казаками, носившими чуб.(протоболгарское слово с аланским корнем "хъхол" означает "змея",специфичный чуб украинцев, который был похож на змею, мог стать основанием, чтобы их называли этим словом когда-то давно).Возможно, слово это изначально вошло в РУССКОязычный лексикон именно как уничижительное название украинцев Но теперь так не воспринимается, если только националистами. Уж слишком часто оно употреблялось в литературе, и вообще в жизни, без оскорбляющих ноток, разве что с оттенком юмора-иронии. Вот фамильярное - да,а это сейчас тоже не приветствуется.

Так что Вы правильно сделали замечание, но проблема в том, что сейчас всякое замечание воспринимается как "наезд", так что лучше замечаний тоже не делать. Время такое.

Comment: >Вот КАЦАП, [араб. ḳaṣṣāb — мясник]  
  
Странная все-таки этимология...
Согласен, от "как цап" - еще менее убедительна, но тут из серии "обе хуже"

Интересное обсуждение здесь  
http://lingvoforum.net/index.php/topic,2335.0.html

Comment: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/832638 КАЦА́П, (араб. kassab - мясник) (дорев. бран.). Шовинистическое обознач. русского в отличие от украинца. «Проклятые кацапы едят щи даже с тараканами.»Гоголь.Толковый словарь Ушакова. Д.Н. Ушаков. 1935-1940.
http://blackchildren.livejournal.com/24486.htmlhttp://blackchildren.livejournal.com/24486.html Другой вариант происхождения — от арабского qasab — мясник, живодер, через тюркские языки сначала попавшего в русский и украинский языки. Соблюдавшим законы халяля татарам диетарные обычаи русских казались живодерством.

Comment: Что-то какая-то односторонняя политкорректность получается. "Кацап", значит, бранное, а вот "хохол" - нет? Все народы равны, но русские все равно равнее?))))  
Кстати, "цап" — по-украински "козел", и называли так русских из-за того, что они носили бороду, в то время как на Украине больше были приняты усы. И чем это отличается от прозвища "хохол" из-за национальной прически?  
Я тоже не националистка, но слово "хохол" всегда слышу с оттенком высокомерия, а это, поверьте, неприятно. Так же, как евреям, наверное, неприятно слышать по своему адресу слово "жид".

Comment: Любое прозвище неприятно слышать, но прозвища бывают разные: Серый вместо Сергей звучит не обидно, а Шибздик уже обидно,так и здесь: Хохол из-за чуба в виде хохла не обидно, а кацап со смыслом "козёл" или "живодёр" - обидно. Хотя я против ЛЮБЫХ прозвищ, они отказывают в уважении, носят сниженный характер, а национальный вопрос сейчас очень больной.

Comment: Лично мне всё равно, называйте хоть "финно-монголо-кацапкой", хоть горшком. Человек (и народ) с адекватной самооценкой болезненным самолюбием не страдает. Только в печь не пытайтесь ставить. Чревато.

Answer (score 1):

> Не будет сейчас касаться американский маразмов

Вам не кажется, что Вы поступаете неполикорректно? Оскорбили походя, а касаться не хотите? Прям Задорнов какой-то.

По сути. Давно известно, что оскорбление это то, что сочтет оскорблением тот, кого так назвали. Объективности в этом вопросе нет и быть не может. Всё завит от менталитета, культурной среды, конкретной ситуации, контекста. 
Решать вам. Тем, кто говорит и кому говорят.
Но не доводите до абсурда. Будет хуже чем у американцев.

> > Откуда ж, приятель, 
> > Песня твоя: 
> > «Гренада, Гренада, Гренада моя»? 
> > Он медлит с ответом, 
> > Мечтатель-хохол: 
> > '- Братишка! Гренаду Я в книге нашел.

Михаил Светлов

Это тоже осокобительно?

Comment: То есть, по-вашему, например, запрет на слова "мама" и "папа" в некоторых штатах - это нормальная политкорректность, а не маразм? Ну-ну...

Comment: Ой, только сейчас заметил.  
Нет, это-то считаю. Это маразм. Хотя сомневаюсь в достоверности. 
Но "неполиткорректность" была в том, что неназванный(!) маразм характеризуется эпитетом (а что это еще в таком контексте?) Американский - национальной окраской.  
Читатель понятия не имеет, о чем речь - и может думать (не приведи Господи!), об избрании Обамы на второй срок.

Answer (score 1):

"араб. kassab - мясник ; другой вариант происхождения — от арабского qasab - мясник" Понять не могу - почему ДРУГОЙ вариант, когда это одно и то же слово - قَصَّابٌ 
просто передано в неправильной латинской транскрипции.

Comment: Кстати, я - именно хохол, слово "украинец" презираю, т.к. оно означает "житель польской колонии", а хохол - это козак. Звучит гордо. Кстати во времена козаков они назывались и все соседи их называли не "украинцами", а русинами (ударение на первом гласном).